# Google Cloud Storage ACL with expiry time

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm building an application using Google Cloud Storage where users will be able to share their files with other users for a period of time that they choose. After that, the permission to view the file will be revoked.

One way would be to generate [signed urls](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) and share those.
However, I'd like to use [ACL](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/create-manage-lists#storage-set-acls-nodejs) instead since it's much cleaner to use I think. When a user shares a file I can simply add the new user to the ACL with an expiry time.
So basically, the following code with some kind of a time attribute to automatically remove user1 from the acl after, say, *t* seconds.

```
storage
  .bucket(bucketName)
  .file(filename)
  .acl.readers.addUser(user1)
  .then(() => {
    console.log(`Added user ${user1} as an owner on file ${filename}.`);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('ERROR:', err);
  });
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible via builtin functionality. You would have to use some third-party scheduling service, create a cron job that checks for expired ACLs every so often, or create a mirco-service that monitors your ACLs expiration table and automatically removes when expiry occurs.